# "highlighting fields that are wrong"

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am creating my first LWC! YAY! I am learning lots, however, there is so much I do not know so I am assuming there is a better way to do this.

Basically, I have a bunch of date fields that I have displayed in the order that they are supposed to be in. For part of the opportunity, and in some scenarios, the dates aren't required to be in the right order. I have validation rules to take care of the exceptions and make the fields required at certain stages.

My goal is to "highlight" fields if they are wrong. For example, the 'RFI release' should be before the 'RFI Submission'

I have the logic working where my rules are highlighting the fields and displaying all the error messages that apply. See the 1st screenshot for how I have displayed the different ways I have tried highlighting (background-color, border-color, color).
[image]

I am wondering if someone can think of a better way to "highlight" the field. Can I put a border just around the field value like this:
[image]

I put the border around the field label plus value as I seen in the screenshot above, however, I don't think it looks good:

Comment: Your wording is confusing: "Can I put a border just around the field value and not around the whole field?" Can you please [edit] this so it makes more sense?

Comment: Also, PS, without some code, it's going to be hard to help you get where you want to go. LWC has a number of ways to show fields, so we need to know what you've done so far so we can help you progress.

Comment: @sfdcfox , I have updated the wording and here is the code 
https://gist.github.com/lr622349/cf0406693343bd5fba7a5ec35bec7883

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `lightning-input`, you can use its `setCustomValidity` and `reportValidity` functions.  For example:

```html
<template>
  <lightning-input
    data-id="startDate"
    type="date"
    label="Start Date"
    value={startDate}
    onchange={handleChange}
  ></lightning-input>
  <lightning-input
    data-id="endDate"
    type="date"
    label="End Date"
    value={endDate}
    onchange={handleChange}
  ></lightning-input>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class LwcApp extends LightningElement {
  @track startDate;
  @track endDate;

  handleChange(event) {
    this[event.target.dataset.id] = event.target.value;
    this.validateDates();
  }

  validateDates() {
    let dateFields = [...this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")];
    // If both date fields are populated and Start Date is greater than End
    // Date, set a validation message on both
    if (
      dateFields.every((f) => f.value) &&
      new Date(dateFields[0].value) > new Date(dateFields[1].value)
    ) {
      let message = "End Date must not be earlier than Start Date";
      dateFields.forEach((f) => f.setCustomValidity(message));
      // Otherwise, clear the validation message
    } else {
      dateFields.forEach((f) => f.setCustomValidity(""));
    }
    // Force each field to update its validity display
    dateFields.forEach((f) => f.reportValidity());
  }
}
```

[See `lightning-input` reference docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification)

Comment: If this answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it "accepted" -- thanks!